# Vertical align nav in header along with the title

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to get the navigation to `vertical-align: middle;` along with the title. Any idea how to fix this issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/ozvmkeaq/

```css
header,
nav {
  height: 80px;
}
header {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ECF0F1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.title {
  float: left;
}
.title h1 a {
  color: #ECF0F1;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="title">
    <h1><a href="index.html"> HTTP</a></h1>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="pioneers.html">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="pioneers.html">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="pioneers.html">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the following CSS, the links vertically center.

```
ul { margin: 0; height: 100%; display: table; width: 100%;}
nav ul li {    height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;}
```

I've also updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ozvmkeaq/2/

Basically, you need the combination of table and vertical-align properties to tell the browser you want the content in the middle.

As as an alternative, you can also use flex-box.

display: flex;
align-items: center;

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `vertical-align:middle` to the list items themselves. I would also set it to the links directly to compensate for any list item padding etc.

For example:

```
nav ul li, nav ul li a{vertical-align:middle;}
```

This is because vertical-align sets the position based on the parent element, so you need to set it to the child element (different from properties such as text-align where you can set the style to the parent element to affect the elements within).

See more on vertical align at the [W3C vertical-align property guide](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).

Or [Try it here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header {
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    height: 5em;
    position: relative;
}

header * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav, header .title {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

header .title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

header .title h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.70em;
}

header .title a {
    color: #ECF0F1;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}

header nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
}

header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    position: relative;
    top: 2em;
    right: 0;
}

header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update this 2 style and it should do the trick.

```
nav ul
{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

nav li
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    line-height: 80px;
    background-color: green;
}
```